# Calendar CSS issue with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The items in the last row of my calendars are displayed centered instead of left aligned. 
[image]

If i remove boostrap's CSS, they are correct aligned. 
[image]

I cant find the conflicting CSS with bootstrap. 
**Can anybody please help?**

> **UPDATE:** with bootstrap 4 everything is fine. but unfortunaly i need a bootstrap 3 solution.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] (including code) to your question.  Otherwise it's nearly impossible to tell *exactly* where the issue lies

Comment: sorry, here a pen: https://codepen.io/exotec/pen/jpyyPM

Comment: You have to remove the hidden attribute and replace that with the disabled attribute for the last row

Comment: Sorry, but i dont know what you mean. Where did you see an hidden attribute?